# What are the color names available for scale_color_manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[This page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html) shows how to use `scale_color_manual` in R.  It gives red, green, and blue as possible color values.

What values are available?

How do I see what values are available?  (Say I've loaded or made a new palette.)

Comment: The same as the [color names available in R](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf). A palette is an object itself, it doesn't create new color names. See `?colors`

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/colors.html

Comment: If you submit `colors()` as an answer, I will accept. @Gregor @Roland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is special about the color names available in ggplot - they are the same as the color names available in R. You can use `colors()` to see the the list, with details at `?colors`. I generally prefer to search the web for "[R colors](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=r%20colors)" because your first hit will almost certainly be a document that shows the colors with the color names.

> Say I've loaded or made a new palette.

A palette is an object that contains colors. It can contain named or un-named colors. Palettes do not change the named colors that are available.

Comment: I googled a bunch for "r scale_color_manual" and didn't find this result, so thanks.